# Apache: How to avoid domain.com/.htaccess rules to sub.domain.com that is located under domain.com DocumentRoot?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp, virtualhost

How to avoid domain.com/.htaccess rules to sub.domain.com that is located under domain.com  `DocumentRoot`?

- domain.com `DocumentRoot /domain`
- sub.domain.com `DocumentRoot /domain/sub`
- dir **/domain**/.htaccess : `Redirect 301 /art http://domain.com/article/art`
- no .htaccess under dir **/domain/sub**

Why also sub.domain.com/art has 301 redirect to domain.com/article/art, if just domain.com has this rules?

Is it maybe some XAMPP 1.7.4 bug?

**Update:** It does not work with it either (sub.domain.com/art still returns 301 redirect to domain.com/article/art):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /domain
    ServerName domain.com
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /domain>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /domain/sub
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /domain/sub>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to avoid using .htaccess and use virtualhosts.

One VirtualHost for domain.com.

One VirtualHost for subdomain.com.

inside each VirtualHost you can define `<Directory />` and `<Directory /domain>` for the first one, and `<Directory />` and `<Directory /domain/sub>` for the second one. Then remove all .htaccess or use **AllowOverride None** in the `<Directory />` (same effect). You'll see as well that apache is faster when he doesn't have to check for existence of .htaccess in all parent directories.

All **Directory** instructions can contains exactly the same thing as what you usually use in .htaccess. .htaccess is a way to let someone define some *Directory* instructions when you don't want him to edit apache configuration files; But .htaccess files are done to be related with directory tree inheritance.

Comment: I updated my question with code example recording to your suggestion. Unfortunately sub.domain.com/art still returns me 301 redirect to domain.com/article/art. Some other solution?

Comment: 301 are memorized by browser, test after a close of your browser (and cache wipeout). test as well from telnet (if you knwo how to HTTP via telnet).

Comment: check as well you o not have any Directory option defined in your main apache configuration (and which apply for all vitualhosts by the way).and remove the .htaccess, if you do not have any redirect rules anywhre, you should'nt have a redirect happening

Comment: Thanks! If works now well, after I unset `AllowOverride All` in httpd.conf `<Directory /xampp/htdocs>` and I added only one Directory for each VirtualHost, like `<Directory /domain>AllowOverride All</Directory>` and `<Directory /domain/sub>AllowOverride All</Directory>`.